# CSS very thin font?

Tags: html, css

How do I create very thin fonts with CSS, like at http://www.google.com/landing/newgadgets/ ?

Right now I'm using this, but I'm on a mac and I don't think "Helvetica Neue" is supported on windows.

```
h1{
  font-size:64px;
  font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
}
```

Any ideas for thin, crisp fonts?

Comment: Helvetica Neue is supported on Windows if it's installed. It's *really ugly* on Windows though.

Comment: You have to quote any font values that have spaces, should be `font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: Shouldn't "Helvetica Neue" be surrounded by quotes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google is using their *font API* and CSS's `@font-face`

See the following reference in their code:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;subset=latin" rel="stylesheet">
```

Below is the exact definition that *"registers"* said font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v5/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Then they simply apply that font to element/s:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, blockquote, q, .maia-nav ul {
   font-family: 'open sans',arial,sans-serif;
}
```

***Note:*** `@font-face` fonts don't render crisply on downlevel browsers. If you need to support them try - http://cufon.shoqolate.com/

Comment: What is a "down-level" browser?

Comment: @BoltClock term used to describe *older browsers* - here is a post that uses that term: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Just grab that font from [Google's Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

Select the fonts you want, select the styles (**bold**, *italic*, etc.) and Google will give you a `<link />` element to include in your HTML.

That current font is called **Open Sans**:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Now you can use it:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 5):

I use Google Fonts.  A thin example:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway

Comment: +1 I was looking for the closest font to Helvetica Neue. Thank you!