# HTML Coding - How to create very thin fonts using HTML

Tags: html

I am creating a website through godaddy.com which is one of the idiotic website builder. I am frustrated by going to godaddy.com.

Could any one please help me out how do I create Thin fonts in HTML like how google fonts are where we can reduce the thickness of the fonts. I tried directly using google fonts in my website builder, but it is not supported. I need the Thin fonts which can support to all browsers like google.com, IE, FireFox, Safari etc.

Hope to receive replies and will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706023/css-very-thin-font?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an HTML attribute like "style=" and you import some CSS features.

The [CSS property you search for is `font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight):

```
font-weight: ; (Values: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900)
```

I hope this helped.